# What do you think about my proof of (a mod n = a ⇔ a < n )

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Proof:

Let $a, n, q,$ $r\in \mathbb Z$

$\Longrightarrow$: Assume we have $a \mod n = a$ and we want to show that this implies a < n.

By definition of modulo we can re-write $a \mod n$:

$a = qn + a$

For this to exist: $a < n $

$\Longleftarrow$ : Assume we have $a < n.$ So, there exist $n = qn + r$.

We want to show that this implies $a \mod n = a$.

This is equivalent to say that $a = qn + a$ (again by definition).

We take $a = r  < n $ and we have $a = qn + a$

Which is equivalent to say that $a \mod n = a$

End.

Shall I improve something? (i'm a beginner)

Comment: `mod` in many pure mathematical contexts is not an operator like this.  You seem to be using the compSci version of mod where it is an operator that returns a single output at a time.  You have written $a\in \Bbb Z$ which would include negative $a$ values... $-10$ is less than $5$.  Is $-10 \text{ mod } 5 = -10$?  Do you mean instead to have $a,n\in\Bbb N$ instead?  Note also that definitions vary as to what to do about negative values across different programming languages.  Some would have $-3\text{ mod }5=-3$ while others would have $-3\text{ mod }5=2$

Comment: In my opinion both of these directions are unclear.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think that defining $a \bmod m$ to be the unique $r$ such that $m \mid (a-r)$ and $0 \le r < m$ is standard in mathematical contexts. I agree that, when giving the definition, the definition should be given completely.

Comment: @JMoravitz When used as an operation, some authors define for all integer (or even for all reals) $a \bmod b = a-b\lfloor a/b \rfloor$ (if $b\ne 0$). This is consistent with the proposition that the OP is proving

Comment: I am not disagreeing with that.  I am just pointing out to be careful since there is inconsistency prevalent in the real world.  It also does not contradict my counterexample to the claim when we still allow for negative values to occur, which should be taken as a suggestion to the OP that they need to correct their post with a more accurate problem statement in order to have what they are trying to prove to actually be true.

Comment: @MishaLavrov The first part of your definition is equivalent to OPs a = qn + a, and the second part is exactly what OP tries to prove.

Comment: @gnasher729 The second part *must* be part of the definition, or else there can be multiple values of $a \bmod n$. It's possible that another equivalent definition is in play, but then *that* needs to be stated.

Comment: @JMoravitz You're right. For the proposition to be true one needs to consider it in the natural numbers or change the inequality to $0\le a < n$

Comment: @jjagmath yes I should have said that everything : a, n, q, r are in N not in Z . Sorry for this mistake. Apart from that is this a  valid proof?